# Add certain text at end of certain lines in VBS

Tags: vbscript, data-manipulation, find-replace

I have a .txt file which I wish to edit in VBS. The data is like the following:

```
Time, Column 1, Column 2
23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM, Data, Data
23/08/2017 8:35:00 AM, Data, Data
23/08/2017 8:40:00 AM, Data, Data
23/08/2017 8:45:00 AM, Data, Data
```

What I want is another 'column' called *batch* added at the end of the first line and then, the first value of time (`23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM`) to make up the data for this column so that the end result is something like the following:

```
Time, Column 1, Column 2, Batch
23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM, Data, Data, 23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM
23/08/2017 8:35:00 AM, Data, Data, 23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM
23/08/2017 8:40:00 AM, Data, Data, 23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM
23/08/2017 8:45:00 AM, Data, Data, 23/08/2017 8:30:00 AM
```

Note a comma separator exists between each column.

Comment: Can you post your code pointing out where you are facing the issue?

Comment: Hi kira. I actually don't have a great idea on how to go about this in vbs. But am working on something. Will post what I end up with in a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

- Start reading the data from the File line by line and store it in a temporary variable along with the data you want to append at the end of each line.
- For the first line, data to be appended is ", Batch" and for the remaining lines data to be appended is the "Time Value" from the 2nd Line.
- Open the file in write mode and write the data stored in that temporary variable

Code:

```
strPath = "C:\Users\gr.singh\Desktop\Desktop\Gurman\2017\as.txt"    'Replace this path with your file path
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set rfile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath,1)                'File opened in Read-only mode
While Not rfile.AtEndOfStream
    temp=rfile.ReadLine()
    If rfile.Line=2 Then                               'The first line has been read by using the readline method due to which rfile.line gets set to 2. Hence, I have used 2 here for the 1st line. Similarly, I have used 3 fro the 2nd line in the ElseIf Condition
        dataToAppend = "Batch"
    ElseIf rfile.Line=3 Then
        dataToAppend = Split(temp,",")(0)
    End If
    fulldata = fulldata & temp&", "&dataToAppend&"||"
Wend
rfile.Close
fulldata = Left(fulldata,Len(fulldata)-2)
Set wfile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath,2)                'File opened in write mode
tempArr = Split(fulldata,"||")
For i=0 To UBound(tempArr)
    wfile.WriteLine tempArr(i)
Next
wfile.Close
Set fso= Nothing
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: Handling the first line separately from the rest would make the code a little simpler (because you wouldn't need a condition inside the loop). Also, if you're going with reading the file in a loop I'd write the output to a temp file and replace the original file afterwards, otherwise it'd be simpler to read the entire file, split it at newlines, then write it back after modifying the lines.

Comment: Hi Ansgar. Thanks for your help. Yes this approach is pretty good and the code works well. Thanks to it I got some other ideas on how to approach text file editing. Thanks again

Comment: Valid points @Ansgar. Should have done that way but this came to my mind first, hence posted. I guess I should leave that for OP as he must have gotten fair bit of idea about the solution to his problem by now.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is reasonably small you can read it as a whole and process it like this:

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt  = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
data = Split(txt, vbNewLine)

If UBound(data) >= 0 Then data(0) = data(0) & ",batch"
If UBound(data) >= 1 Then
  batchval = Left(data(1), InStr(data(1), ",")-1)
  data(1) = data(1) & "," & batchval
End If
For i = 2 To UBound(data)
  data(i) = data(i) & "," & batchval
Next

fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2).Write Join(data, vbNewLine)
```

For large files this approach is not recommended, though, because it may lead to memory exhaustion, causing your computer to come grinding to a halt. If your file is large you're better off processing the file line by line, writing the output to a temporary file, and replacing the original once you're finished.

```
filename    = "C:\path\to\your.txt"
tmpfilename = filename & ".tmp"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(tmpfilename, 2, True)

If Not inFile.AtEndOfStream Then outFile.WriteLine inFile.ReadLine & ",batch"
If Not inFile.AtEndOfStream Then
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  batchval = Left(line, InStr(line, ",")-1)
  outFile.WriteLine line & "," & batchval
End If
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  outFile.WriteLine inFile.ReadLine & "," & batchval
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

fso.DeleteFile filename, True
fso.MoveFile tmpfilename, filename
```

Comment: The last/added column should contain the time of the first (not the corresponding) row. (So instead of changing the file, one should adapt the retrival.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I would stick with the general approach, though, only handle the first 2 lines differently instead of just the first line.